# How to configure graphics tablet to use just one monitor with XFCE?

Tags: xfce, tablet, hid

The graphics tablet I use, works as expected with Gnome 3. I can use absolute positioning on my multi monitor setup. I've set one of my two monitors to be used with the graphics tables. This way, if you draw a circle, you actually get a circle.

On XFCE, the tablet works fine, but I can't set it to use just one monitor. This means, that on my multi monitor setup, it is quite unusable. If you draw a circle, you get a pretty squashed ellipse.

I haven't found a setting for that as of yet.

The tablet is a "Waltop A".

Comment: What version of Xfce? 4.10 is quite limited in handling two monitors, but the upcoming 4.12 should have better support. Also, did you play with `arandr`?